# Why my custom command wouldn't work over sudo in zsh?

Tags: zsh, sudo, oh-my-zsh

I have added following custom function in my `~/.zshrc`, but I get command not found when I run it with sudo.

```
woodo() {
    if [ $EUID != 0 ]; then
      echo "It's a weird tree."
    else
        echo '     _              __'
        echo '    / `\  (~._    ./  )'
        echo '    \__/ __`-_\__/ ./'
        echo '   _ \ \/  \   \ |_   __'
        echo ' (   )  \__/ -^    \ /  \'
        echo '  \_/ "  \  | o  o  |.. /  __'
        echo "       \\. --' ====  /  || /  \\ "
        echo '         \   .  .  |---__.\__/'
        echo '         /  :     /   |   |'
        echo '         /   :   /     \_/'
        echo '      --/ ::    ('
        echo '     (  |     (  (____'
        echo '   .--  .. ----**.____)'
        echo '   \___/          '
    fi
}
```

---

```
$ woodo
It's a weird tree.
$ sudo woodo
sudo: woodo: command not found
```

I also modified it to check `$UID`, (as suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/688573/how-do-i-tell-if-zsh-is-running-with-privileges)), but still it wouldn't work:

```
...
if [[ $UID !=0 || $EUID != 0 ]]; then
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `sudo woodo` runs `woodo` as root, not as a normal user. I'm not an expert on `sudo`, but my guess is that is starts a new shell, possibly `bash` not `zsh`, as root. Therefore your personal `~/.zshrc` is not involved. And even if `sudo` does use `zsh`, it might initialize with `/root/.zshrc`.

Either way, your personal `~/.zshrc` is not used under `sudo`.

Comment: Thank you! I added this as a file in `/usr/local/bin` and works now.

Comment: `sudo` requires an executable file, something it can pass to `execve`, as the command to run. Shell functions, aliases, and other arbitrary shell commands are excluded.